# RS2008 Background Image Sizing

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

So I'm attempting to create a report that is able to pre-fill a "government form" with Reporting Services 2008.

Now this all falls down to the 96 DPI issue everyone seems to be having.

Let's say I have a 300 DPI high res JPG file that I want to use as a background image for a report. (This jpg is actually a scan of the government form I'm trying to prefill)

When you set the Fill option of a rectangle object (or even the entire report body) - you have no option but for it to be it's original size. I cannot seem to get the image to fit proportional to the size of my rectangle.

If I add the image as a ... "image object" - I get my desired right *shock horror* - because I can select the sizing option "fit proportional" and then resize my "image object" as I desire.

BUT - you cannot overlay textboxes over the top of an image object. And because my image object contains fields I'm trying to prefill from a dataset - it fails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok so I managed to figure this out.

For those interested, read this guide and DOWNLOAD THE SAMPLE PROJECT for an example (ignore the stuff regarding showing/hiding high/low res versions - I merely used the example to see how they were able to overlay textboxes ontop of images).

http://www.infoq.com/articles/Gogolowicz-Swanson-SSRS

You need to keep an eye on an objects parent. Keep in mind these notes;

Page_1 rectangle needs to have a parent of BaseRectangle.

Page_1_Image needs to have a parent of BaseRectangle.

All page1 textboxes need to have a parent of the Page_1 rectangle etc.

It all makes sense now.

Comment: Thanks Jamsi. I found the linked document a while ago, then lost it and was never able to find it again. Finally got my SSRS overlays working after reading your post. Much appreciated and your comments helped me understand better what they were wanting.